# Error when writing a table into a Power BI Datamart db [CREATE TABLE permission denied in database..]

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database, ssms, datamart

I'm curious to know whether or not it is possible to create a table in Datamart using SQL Server Management Studio. Just a note, Power BI Datamart uses Azure SQL db. I have tried to do it using the following query:

```
 
SELECT Role = r.name, Member = m.name 
FROM sys.database_role_members as rm
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals as r
    ON r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals as m
    ON m.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
```

and I get the following error:

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'db_powerbiprodgbr_20221028_10054574_fb38'.

```
 SELECT Role = r.name, Member = m.name  FROM sys.database_role_members as rm INNER JOIN sys.database_principals as r     ON r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id INNER JOIN sys.database_principals as m     ON m.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
```

I then wanted to change my role from admin to admin_user using the following query:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::db_powerbiprodgbr_20221028_10054574_fb38 TO admin_user
```

When I attempted to change my privilege I got the following error:

> Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> User does not have permission to perform this action.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Okay. I have now removed the images.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please run the following statement on the Azure SQL database while logged in as the SQL Admin login of the logical server?

exec sp_addRoleMember 'dbmanager', 'powerbilogin'

After that powerbilogin will be able to create tables.

Comment: I have just tried running the query, unfortunately I received the following error: `User or role 'powerbilogin' does not exist in this database.`. I ran a quick query, the users on the db are **Username**: _admin_user_  **Role**: _admin_ and **Username**: _dbo_ **Role**:  _db_owner_. I currently log in as 'admin_user'.

Comment: Please change Powerbilogin by the login name you are using on PowerBI. Change it to admin_user.